# How can I implement a number of attempts here

Tags: java

I ask the user if he has a promo code, if there is I give him the opportunity to enter it, I want to make him have 3 attempts for correct entry.

This is how I tried:

```
public void chooseClassAndPromoCode(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
    System.out.println("Pick which class do you want? (1 - economic, 2 - business, 3 - first class)");
    int userFlightClass = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Do you have promo code? (yes / no )");
    String yesNoPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();
    int attempts = 3;
    if (yesNoPromoCode.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Enter promo code");
        String userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();

        while (attempts-- > 0) {
            if (userPromoCode.equals(selectedFlight.getPromoCode()) && userFlightClass == 1) {
                System.out.println("Price for economic class is: " + selectedFlight.getPriceForEconomicClass());
               // System.out.println("Promo code is valid. You have discount of: 20%, new price is: " + discountEconomyClass());
                System.out.println("Balance of: " + selectedPassenger.getFirstName() + " is: " + selectedPassenger.getBalance());
          //      payingEconomicClassWithPromoCode(flightList);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrent. Number of atempts: " + attempts);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

After I run it, program print me this:

```
Incorrent. Number of atempts: 2
Incorrent. Number of atempts: 1
Incorrent. Number of atempts: 0
```

Comment: What is your actual question/problem? what does not work as you wish it to work? what is desired and actual outputs' difference(s)?

Comment: Put your code to enter the promo code inside the while loop. You'll need to add a break so you get out of the loop when there's a good code.

Comment: You are only getting input from the user once at the beginning. When the loop is running, it checks using the same input over and over, not giving the user the opportunity to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Justo fix the placement of the `userPromoCode` scanner, it should be inside the `while`.

```
public void chooseClassAndPromoCode(ArrayList<Flight> flightList) {
System.out.println("Pick which class do you want? (1 - economic, 2 - business, 3 - first class)");
int userFlightClass = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Do you have promo code? (yes / no )");
String yesNoPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();
int attempts = 3;
String userPromoCode = ""
if (yesNoPromoCode.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    while (attempts-- > 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter promo code");
        userPromoCode = scanner.nextLine();
        if (userPromoCode.equals(selectedFlight.getPromoCode()) && userFlightClass == 1) {
            System.out.println("Price for economic class is: " + selectedFlight.getPriceForEconomicClass());
           // System.out.println("Promo code is valid. You have discount of: 20%, new price is: " + discountEconomyClass());
            System.out.println("Balance of: " + selectedPassenger.getFirstName() + " is: " + selectedPassenger.getBalance());
      //      payingEconomicClassWithPromoCode(flightList);
              break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrent. Number of atempts: " + attempts);
        }
    }
}
```

}